# Is dinoprost PGF2-alpha or PGE2?

Tags: pharmacology

In many places it says PGF2-alpha. 
Now, I am thinking PGE2 is a substype of PGF2-alpha. 
However, I am not sure.

Is dinoprost PGE2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prostaglandins A,B,C,D,E,F represent different **non-inclusive** classes of prostaglandins and all have different chemical structure. Hence (by classification), PgE cannot be subtype of PgF:

PgE have an **oxo** group at C9, while PgF have **hydroxyl** group at C9.

Back to Dinoprost, it is PgF2alpha and not PgE2 which **is** Dinoprostone.